# FTPS connection stalled on TLS initialization?

Tags: configuration, tls, ftps

I am very good with an HTTP server, but I am new to FTP. I'm trying to configure a FTPS connection and I have listen set to port 990. But FileZilla client connection always hangs up on TLS initialization and then times out. Any suggestions on configuration? This is my current FTPS config:

```
Enable FTP over SSL/TLS support (FTPS) - Checked
Allow explicit FTP over TLS - Checked
    Disallow plain unencrypted FTP - Checked
Force PROT P to encrypt file transfers in SSL/TLS mode - Checked
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your client trying to negotiate a passive connection to the FTPS server that it won't allow? It may be requesting the switch to PASV and the server is unable to connect because of firewall restrictions.